# What's the significance of the trucks in these scenes?

Tags: analysis, preacher

In the episode *Bleak City* from **Preacher** (Season 4 episode 5) there are 2 scenes that caught my eye:

- When Jesse is driving out of the parking lot a truck comes unexpectedly from one side, he suddenly brake and then notices Eugene.
- Not much later on, he's at an intersection and again a truck rushes by from the side, forcing him to brake. He pauses and changes direction again.

He doesn't seem confused with the right-hand driving (he drives around fine after the first time he gets in the car from the wrong side). Is there anything significant with trucks in Australia, is this a common TV trope or is it just a cheap plot device to move the story forward?